# matrix exponential - Is such behavior expected?

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

I was experimenting on $e^M$ and found this:

When $ M = \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & x \\ y & 0 \end{matrix} \right] $

$e^M = \left[ \begin{matrix} cosh(\sqrt{xy}) & \sqrt{x\over{y}}sinh(\sqrt{xy}) \\
      \sqrt{y\over{x}}sinh(\sqrt{xy}) & cosh(\sqrt{xy}) \end{matrix} \right]$

[WolframAlpha Results 1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrixexp(%7B%7B0,x%7D,%7By,0%7D%7D))

Expressing $M = A + B$, where 
$ A = \left[ \begin{matrix} a & x \\ 0 & a \end{matrix} \right] $ and 
$ B = \left[ \begin{matrix} -a & 0 \\ y & -a \end{matrix} \right] $, gives

$e^M = e^{A+B} = e^Ae^B =
\left[ \begin{matrix} e^a & xe^a \\ 0 & e^a \end{matrix} \right]
\left[ \begin{matrix} e^{-a} & 0 \\ ye^{-a} & e^{-a} \end{matrix} \right] = 
\left[ \begin{matrix} xy+1 & x \\ y & 1 \end{matrix} \right]$

[WolframAlpha Results 2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrixexp(%7B%7Ba,x%7D,%7B0,a%7D%7D)matrixexp(%7B%7B-a,0%7D,%7By,-a%7D%7D))

Is this expected? Or am I doing something wrong? Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming that $$\tag1e^{A+B}=e^Ae^B.$$ This is not true in general; you need $AB=BA$ for $(1)$ to hold.

Comment: seems like i was wrong. here $AB \neq BA$. thanks